# Допустима ли фраза: "С юбилеем со дня рождения!"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Допустима ли фраза: "С юбилеем со дня рождения!"

Comment: @Сибиряк комментарии не предназначены для ответов, см. Мету.

Comment: @Aer Это был не ответ.

Comment: @Сибиряк пожалуйста, обратите внимание на https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/322/178412.

Answer (score 3):

Абсолютно недопустима.

С натяжкой можно поздравить ***с юбилейным днём рождения***.

Comment: Давненько, Галина, мы с Вами не виделись-не слышались. Честное слово, Вас не хватало.

Comment: Риммулик, Я в Кота Индиану играю! Вот будем новую книжку готовить - я приду (сейчас прежняя в стадии выпуска, изд-во АСТ).

Answer (score 2):

Замечу сначала, что в словаре Кузнецова можно встретить такое выражение:

> Столетний юбилей со дня рождения поэта.

Поэтому нет никакой ошибки в том, чтобы поздравить друга "с пятилетним юбилеем со дня рождения сына!". Естественно, это поздравление можно сократить, например, так: "с пятилетним юбилеем!" или просто "с юбилеем!" (остальное очевидно из контекста). Но вряд ли кто сочтёт разумным в этой ситуации сокращенное поздравление "с юбилеем со дня рождения!".

Другое дело, если у друга в один день два юбилея: день рождения и день свадьбы. А вы хотите подчеркнуть, что поздравляете его только с первым. Почему бы нет?

Answer (score 0):

У фразы курьезное значение, но ведь семантика не запрещает... "Юбилей" в широком смысле может быть у любого события, то есть и у дня рождения тоже.
Получается масло масляное. И если поздравляющий именно такой иронический смысл вкладывает во фразу, а принимающий поздравление это понимает, то почему бы и нет? Грамматика не запрещает, это даже не семантический эрратив.

В серьезных случаях, разумеется, надо избегать.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза "...со дня рождения..." обычно употребляется по отношению к людям умершим, так как они не дожили до тех лет, о которых идёт речь. Например, "...торжества по случаю столетия со дня рождения Иванова Петра Сидоровича...", который, допустим, прожил девяносто девять лет и скончался на сотом году жизни. Что касаемо живых, то обычно говорится " поздравил/поздравляю с юбилеем, или пятидесятилетием".
Особо можно выделить тех людей, которые любят поздравлять с "пятидесятым днём рождения", даже не утруждая себя посчитать какой день рождения сегодня празднует новорождённый. Именно новорождённый, а не именинник, так как именины - это день Ангела. Если день рождения и именины совпадают, то можно здравить, то есть поздравлять именинника. А что относительно счёта дней рождения, то не следует путать дни рождения с годами жизни. Лет может быть и пятьдесят, но дней рождения пятьдесят один, ведь день в который родился человек почему-то многие не считают за первый, а считают за нулевой, возможно по аналогии с линейкой, где шкала начинается с нуля.