# Можно ли так писать: "200-летие со дня рождения"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Из Википедии. [Памятные монеты России](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8#%C2%AB%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%C2%BB).

> 200-летие со дня рождения Н. В. Гоголя
>   200-летие со дня рождения А. С. Пушкина
>   250-летие со дня рождения М.Ю. Лермонтова

По-моему, 200-летие — это дата, событие, а не отрезок времени. Должно быть *200 лет со дня рождения Н. В. Гоголя*, но *200-летие Н. В. Гоголя*. Прав ли я?

Найдено в интернете: "2000-**летие** от Рождества Христова", наряду с "2000 **лет** от рождества Христова". Что скажете?

Дополнение.

Поискал "-летие-" у Кузнецова (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=*%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5*)

У него:

- отметить ВОСЬМИДЕСЯТИЛЕТИЕ отца (понимаю и принимаю).
- ВОСЬМИЛЕТИЕ **со дня** окончания школы (**не понимаю**, по-моему, должно быть ВОСЬМИЛЕТИЕ окончания школы).
- Двадцать лет со дня рождения кого-л -> Отпраздновать ДВАДЦАТИЛЕТИЕ сына(понимаю и принимаю).
- Двадцать пять лет со дня рождения кого-л -> . Отметить ДВАДЦАТИПЯТИЛЕТИЕ дочери (понимаю и принимаю).
- ДВУХСОТЛЕТИЕ битвы (понимаю и принимаю).
- ДЕСЯТИЛЕТИЕ пуска гидроэлектростанции (понимаю и принимаю).

А вот тут еще и "Столетний юбилей со дня рождения поэта" у Кузнецова нашелся.
По-моему, здесь сразу две ошибки. Столетним может быть поэт, а юбилей возраста не имеет. Тем более не может быть ни "столетнего со дня рождения", ни "юбилея со дня рождения". Что же это такое? "Неправильности", которые так закрепились в языке, что стали нормой?

Comment: *Поискал "-летие-" у Кузнецова* — плохо искали :) Там много подходящего. Я дополнил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Толковый словарь Ефремовой тоже отмечает два значения.

**...ле́тие** — конечная часть сложных имен существительных, вносящая значения:

**1)** срок, период, промежуток времени во столько лет, сколько названо в начальной части слова (восьмиле́тие, девятнадцатиле́тие, семиле́тие и т. п.);
**2)** годовщина какого-либо события, происшедшего, начавшегося и т. п. столько лет назад, сколько названо в начальной части слова (восьмидесятиле́тие, восьмисотле́тие, девятиле́тие и т. п.).
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/271810/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5

Годовщина — календарная дата, отмечающая, что со времени какого-либо события прошёл очередной год. Это не обязательно праздник, это может быть и просто дата, год со дня чего-то. Значит, можно сказать: очередная годовщина дня рождения кого-то (в отличие от годовщины дня смерти) и годовщина (год) **со** дня рождения кого-то, годовщина (год) со дня смерти кого-то, годовщина (год) со дня поступления куда-то.

Вот   "Юбилей со дня рождения" — явная избыточность, потому что юбилей — это годовщина **жизни**, ясно, что со дня рождения, а не со дня смерти.

"2000-летие от Рождества Христова" — явная ошибка. **От** — начало исчисления от какого-то события. Я думаю, это какой-нибудь украинский или белорусский сайт — там возможно такое неразличение в бытовой сфере, разговорное. Официальный сайт вряд ли допустит такое выражение, там будет "**2000 лет от Рождества Христова"**.

Comment: *юбилей - это годовщина жизни* — не обязательно. Посмотрите мой ответ в [соседней теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441831/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%a1-%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Answer (score 0):

> 2000-летие Рождества Христова 
>   200-летие со дня рождения Н. В.Гоголя
>  и т.п.

Это не событие и не отрезок времени. Просто название серии монет. А выпуск каждой такой серии приурочен к соответствующему событию.

Upd. Серия монет называется "2000-летие Рождества Христова" (без предлога "от"). В данном случае "в Интернете кто-то ошибся".

**Дополнение.**
В словаре Кузнецова зафиксировано нужное значение слова столетие (например):

> СТОЛЕТИЕ, -я; ср. 
>  2. Годовщина чего-л.,
>   происшедшего или начатого сто лет тому назад. С. отмены крепостного
>   права. С. основания города.

В этом же словаре неоднократно встречаются следующего рода выражения:

> В 2003 г. (будет) трёхсотлетие со дня   основания Петербурга...

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы не поняли вопрос. Для Вас меняю формулировку: можно ли давать такие названия, грамотно ли это?

Comment: @М_Г А, понятно. У меня не получается усомниться. Можно назвать фильм "Взятие Берлина"? Тоже событие.

Comment: Вопрос не в названиях, а в том, правильно ли это вообще: "Юбилей со дня рождения", "200-летие со дня рождения", "Взятие Берлина со дня начала войны"?

Comment: @М_Г Последнее недопустимо, я считаю. Первое зависит от контекста. По поводу **-летия** я дополнил ответ. Надеюсь, я теперь правильно понял Ваш вопрос :)

Comment: @М_Г Про юбилей я высказал свою точку зрения в соответствующей теме.